# Laravel 5.4 project moved from Windows to Linux CentOS 6

Tags: linux, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, centos6

I have 2 issues.

1) I have to type index.php before entering any route path. for example: instead of `www.example.com/login` I have to type: `www.example.com/index.php/login` similarly other routes.

2) I get error `[auth.login]` not found similarly for others. below is the stack-trace

```
(1/1) InvalidArgumentException
View [auth.login] not found.
in FileViewFinder.php (line 137)
at FileViewFinder->findInPaths('auth.login', array('/home/cs/username/blog/resources/views'))
in FileViewFinder.php (line 79)
at FileViewFinder->find('auth.login')
in Factory.php (line 129)
at Factory->make('auth.login', array(), array())
in helpers.php (line 881)
at view('auth.login')
in AuthenticatesUsers.php (line 19)
```

Comment: It looks like you didn't enable mod_rewrite module on linux.